# mysql Select AS

Tags: mysql, reserved-words

i need to do the following select:

```
select distinct type as option from pages
```

but i keep getting errors.
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`option` is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html).

Enclose it in back-ticks or use a different non-reserved-word alias.